# Kotlin Android BLE using nordicsemi cannot get BLE devices

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, nordic-semi

I cannot get BLE devices.

For scan devices, I use `no.nordicsemi.android.kotlin.ble:scanner:1.0.6`

I call `startBleScanning` in the `ViewModel`.

Code:

```
val btDevicesLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
private val aggregator = BleScanResultAggregator()

fun startBleScanning(context: Context) {
    BleScanner(context).scan()
        .map { aggregator.aggregateDevices(it) }
        .onEach {
            btDevicesLiveData.postValue(it.map { device ->
                Log.d("BT", "result: ${device.address}")
            })
        }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

In log, I see paired devices only.

Bluetooth on my phone is enabled.
The device is enabled too.

How can I get BLE devices?

Answer (score -1):

You can add custom settings when you execute the scan function:

A `BleScannerSettings` instance has this structure:

- `scanMode` Set scan mode ([BleScanMode]) for Bluetooth LE scan.
- `reportDelay` Set report delay timestamp for Bluetooth LE scan.
- `includeStoredBondedDevices` Flag indicating weather to include stored bonded devices in scan result.
- `callbackType` Set callback type ([BleScannerCallbackType]) for Bluetooth LE scan.
- `numOfMatches` Set the number of matches ([BleNumOfMatches]) for Bluetooth LE scan filters hardware match.
- `matchMode` Set match mode ([BleScannerMatchMode]) for Bluetooth LE scan filters hardware match.
- `legacy` Set whether only legacy advertisements should be returned in scan results.
- `phy` Set the Physical Layer ([BleScannerPhy]) to use during this scan.

```
val btDevicesLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
private val aggregator = BleScanResultAggregator()

val custom = BleScannerSettings(
    ...
    includeStoredBondedDevices = false,
    ...
)

fun startBleScanning(context: Context) {
    BleScanner(context).scan(settings = custom)
        .map { aggregator.aggregateDevices(it) }
        .onEach {
            btDevicesLiveData.postValue(it.map { device ->
                Log.d("BT", "result: ${device.address}")
            })
        }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Probably you are using legacy devices or you need to check the scan mode by default is `BleScanMode.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please add some context or more explanation about your answer. Also, read about [How to Answer a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write effective answers.